# appended div coming out of the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, append

Here `div` is coming out of the form, i want to show the appended `div` inside the `update_new_1` but the div is coming out of the form.Here is my code

```js
var maxAppend = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.update_more', function() {
  var u_id = $(this).attr("u_id");

  var add_new = $('<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px">\n\
                    <label for="field-1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Document</label>\n\
        <div class="col-sm-5">\n\
        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">\n\
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new" >Select file</span><span class="fileinput-exists" >Change</span><input type="file" name="files[]" ></span> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span><a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput" style="float: none;">&times;</a></div></div>\n\<div class="col-sm-2">\n\<strong>\n\
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Remove</a></strong></div>');
  maxAppend++;
  var resil = $(this).closest("#update_new_" + u_id).append(add_new);
  

});
```

```html
<form method="post" class="form_1" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div id="update_new_1" class="update_new_1 item-row">
  <div class="form-group mb0" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
<label for="field-1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Other Document</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">



  </div>
  <div id="msg_pdf" style="color: #e11221"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <strong>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="update_more"  u_id="1" class="addCF item-row-click update_more">
      <i class="fa fa-plus">
      </i>
      &nbsp;Add More</a>
  </strong>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
     <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/resources/ajax-loader.gif" id="ajaxIndicator" style="display: none; margin-right: 10px" />
                <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-weight: bold" value="Edit Details" />&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As the PHP is irrelevant to the problem could you please edit the question to show the actual HTML output so we can re-create the issue more effectively.

Comment: Code snippets are for code that can be run, you can use normal code blocks for example code (including php code, where relevant (re comment above))

Comment: Can you clarify what "coming out of the form" means?  The easiest way is to provide a working snippet that *demonstrates* the problem.  If you haven't already, have a read of [mcve].

Comment: @freedomn-m `coming out of the form` means `div` is not within `form`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now i had edited my code please have a look

Comment: *"not within form"* is an even more vague rewording of *"coming out of the form"* - is it within the same element ie `<form><div></div></form>` or "not within form" as in `<form></form><div></div>`? or does it have position absolute that means it's "not within form"? or is the div too large for the form element so overflows and is "not within form"?  or is the div simply display:none so "not [visibile] within form"?  **There are many other interpretations.**

Comment: `<form></form><div></div>` the last inserted div is coming like this